# Best practices for actors lookup from actors

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I am using akka 2.2.x. in cluster mode. My question is related to actors lookup.

I have two kind of actors:

- `processor`. It accepts text and processes it somehow
- `result collector`. Acceps messages from `processor` and summarize the results.

`Processor` actor needs to send message to `result collector`. So, I need to have `ActorRef` inside `processor`.

The queston is - how to pass/lookup this `ActorRef` to `processor`.

I have 3 different solutions for now:

1. Lookup `ActorRef` to `processor` in creation time and pass `ActorRef` as contructor parameter. Looks possibly wrong because it does not handle actor restart process and does not fit into cluster environment.
2. Lookup in `preStart` with `context.actorSelection("../result-collector")`. After this I have the object of `ActorSelection` and can send messages with `!`. In this solution I am aware of performance degradation because of lookup in cluster before every call. Or am I wrong here?
3. Lookup in `preStart` with `context.actorSelection("../result-collector")` **and** call `resolveOne` to obtain `ActorRef`. Looks ok, but may not handle akka cluster changes.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you saying #1 is not acceptable?  If you already have the ref then IMO the best way to get that ref to another actor is to either pass in via constructor or pass in right away via a message.  As long as you are using the `ClusterActorRefProvider` then this ref should be "cluster aware" and should survive restarts to the actor that the ref represents.

Comment: Btw, do you prefer #1 above #2 and #3 in general?

Comment: Yes.  It's the more simple of the solutions.  If you already have the ref right there, use it.  Use the other situations where you do not have the ref handy because while they can handle that situation, they are a little more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem, neither with restarts nor with clustering, when using #1. Lookups are only useful in those cases where the ActorRef is not available by any other means.